# Redirection from SpringBoot3 app to Keycloak 22.0.4 realm

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

when accessing to localhost:8081/products I should be redircted to KeycloakRealm authentication page but I've got a 401 Http error
this is application.properties

````
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:products-db
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/my-realm
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}/protocol/openid-connect/certs

jwt.auth.converter.resource-id=products-app
jwt.auth.converter.principle-attribute=preferred_username
keycloak.principal-attribute=name

spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML
#spring.thymeleaf.enabled=false
keycloak.realm=my-realm
keycloak.resource=products-app
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080

keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.ssl-required=none
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

MySecurityConfig Class
```public class SecurityConfig {
    private final JwtAuthConverter jwtAuthConverter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf()
                .disable();


                //.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("HttpMethod.GET","/index")).permitAll()
             //.requestMatchers( new AntPathRequestMatcher("/products/**")).authenticated());


        http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll());
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/index")).permitAll());
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/products")).authenticated());
        //http.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();





        http
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthConverter);

        http
               .sessionManagement()
              .sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS);

        return http.build();
    }
and then this is my Controller
```@Controller
public class ProductController{
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    //@Autowired
    //private KeycloakRestTemplate keycloakRestTemplate;


    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String indexing(){
        return "index";
    }
    @GetMapping("/")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('client-user')")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }
    @GetMapping("/products")
    //@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('client-admin')")
    public String products(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("products",productRepository.findAll());
       return "products";

    }
````